# Using smtpclient to send email outside my domain is not working

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I am trying to send mail using SmtpClient() within my Winforms VB.Net program

Here is the code:

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim _Attachment As String

        If gcloUtilities.GetUser(mHostName, mEMailUser, mEMailPassword, mFromEMail) = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(mEMailUser, mEMailPassword)
        SmtpServer.Port = 587
        SmtpServer.Host = mHostName
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress(mFromEMail)
        mail.To.Add(mfrmSendAnEmail.txtTo.Text)
        mail.Subject = mfrmSendAnEmail.txtSubject.Text

        _Attachment = mDirectory & "\" & gcloGlobals.DocumentName & ".pdf"
        Dim oAttch As Attachment = New Attachment(_Attachment)
        mail.Attachments.Add(oAttch)

        mail.Body = mfrmSendAnEmail.txtBody.Text
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

For Host Name I using mail dot metaprosystems dot com, the user name and password are the user name and password I use to log into my mail server. This work when the To address is within my domain. For example bob at-sign metaprosystems.com. It does not work when I send to an email outside my domain. I get this exception in my catch block:

"Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts (#5.7.1)"

Whether I include an attachment or not doesn’t matter. 
I believe the problem is with my web hosting company, but so far they haven’t come up with a solution. I need so advice as to what to tell them to do to fix this. Alternatively, If I could fix it on my end that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, my host company gave me the answer. I need to use bob at-sign metaprosystems.com instead of just bob as the user. The correct email user name may depend on your host company.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the root issue, but you might want to try enabling SSL on the connection.

```
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
```

**EDIT(1)**
It's also possible that the mail server is implementing a form of POP-BEFORE-SMTP before relaying messages outside of the serviced domain, in which case you might need to establish a POP connection first before trying to send your message. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP3-Client-in-C-NET) is a write-up on how to implement a POP3 client in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It gives me a different exception: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: It's possible that the remote certificate is self-signed and thus your local machine doesn't accept it. You can manually download and install the certificate, or you can try and temporarily set a delegate to allow the certificate. `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) True`

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the E-mail with the Gmail smtp server instead of your own host name.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a mx record to allow the connection to the smtp server

just a thought...

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, my host company gave me the answer. I need to use bob at-sign metaprosystems.com instead of just bob as the user.

The correct email user name may depend on your host company.